# how to select conversation list with one last message with one query

Tags: mysql

i have table conversation

| conversation_id | name | is_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Global chat | 1 |
| 2 | private chat | 0 |

and i have table messages

| message_id | conversation_id | sender_id | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | hello | 06-04-2023 14:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | whatsup | 06-04-2023 14:01:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | hello | 06-04-2023 14:50:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | how are you? | 06-04-2023 14:51:00 |

i need to get with one query conversation list with last message, something like this:

| conversation_id | name | is_group | sender_id | last_message_text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Global chat | 1 | 1 | whatsup | 06-04-2023 14:01:00 |
| 2 | private chat | 0 | 1 | how are you? | 06-04-2023 14:51:00 |

i tried with two query

1. to get all chat list
2. to get last message of chat throught loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` window function to assign a running number for messages per conversation, and then join on the last one:

```sql
SELECT c.*. m.sender_id, m.text AS last_message_text, m.created_at
FROM   conversation c
JOIN   (SELECT conversation_id, sender_id, text, created_at,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY conversation_id 
                                  ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
        FROM   messages) m ON c.conversation_id = m.conversation_id AND rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` to join with a set of max created_at per conversation as follows :

```
select c.*, m.sender_id, m.text_ as last_message_text, m.created_at
from conversation c
inner join messages m on m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
inner join (
  select conversation_id, max(created_at) as max_created_at
  from messages m
  group by conversation_id
) s on s.conversation_id = m.conversation_id and s.max_created_at = m.created_at
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G0pJd2tR)